# How transmission line repeats after \$ \frac{\lambda}{2} \$ distance?

Tags: transmission-line

Following two statements made me think that the transmission line repeates after \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance:

> 1. A complete revolution around the Smith chart corresponds to \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance on the line
> 2. Distance between two successive voltage Maxima is \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$

In order to proof that the line repeates after \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance, my **thoughts** are as follows:
Consider a two conductor transmission line as shown below:
[image]
The instantaneous voltage expression at a distance \$ z \$ on the line is given as :
$$v(z,t)= V_o^+ e^{(- \alpha z)}cos(wt - \beta z) + V_o^- e^{( \alpha z)}cos(wt + \beta z)$$
$$\implies V_s(z) = V_o^+ e^{(- \alpha z)}cos(-\beta z) + V_o^- e^{( \alpha z)}cos(\beta z) \quad \dots (1)$$
Now, \$ cos(\beta z) \$ repeats after a distance of \$ \lambda \$ , then \$ V_s \$ is also supposed to repeat after a distance of \$ \lambda \$;
but according to my conclusion (made in the first line) \$ V_s \$ should repeat after a distance of \$ \frac{\lambda}{2} \$ (as the line repeats after \$ \frac{\lambda}{2} \$ distance)
so, can anyone tell me how \$ V_s \$ repeats after a distance of \$ \frac{\lambda}{2} \$ ?
or any other approach which will prove that the line repeates after \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance

Comment: The zero crossing wavelength....

Comment: Who says the waveform repeats after a distance of \$\frac{\lambda}{2}\$?

Comment: You need to add where you're getting wrong information from. Perhaps there is some context there, (like |Vs| not Vs per Stefan's answer), or a clarification that you're measuring the sending voltage on a mis-terminated line (hence lambda/2 because you're seeing the out-and-back round trip) that might make this correct information.

Comment: @BrianDrummond A complete revolution around the Smith chart corresponds to \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ ; also distance between two successive voltage Maxima is \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ ; so can't we say the line repeats itself after \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance?

Comment: It would be kind of the same as saying that a car wheel repeats itself when the car is moving. It is a repeating pattern, but not a repeating wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The **absolute** value of the voltage \$V_s(z)\$ repeats after \$\lambda/2\$, not \$V_s(z)\$.

Comment: Could you please append to your answer that is it true to say that "the line repeats after \$ \frac{ \lambda}{2} \$ distance " , if yes , then can you please show its derivation