# Transmission Lines:Standaing Wave Voltage Characteristic at Half Wavelength

Tags: transmission-line, telecommunications

The voltage equation for lossless transmission line that my professor has given me is :

$$V(l)=V^+ e^{j\beta l} +V^- e^{-j\beta l}$$

and he says that when singals transits by half the wavelength the characteristics seem to repeat:

but considering that $$\beta =\frac{ 2\pi}{\lambda}$$

if $$l=l+\frac{\lambda}{2},\beta(l+\frac{\lambda}{2})=\beta l+\pi$$ and

$$V(l+\frac{\lambda}{2})=V^+ e^{j\beta l}e^{j\pi} +V^- e^{-j\beta l}e^{-j\pi}=-V(l)$$

So I don't know how he can say that the characteristics repeat or maybe I'am missing something. I'm not sure.

Comment: from the [related questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544457/how-transmission-line-repeats-after-frac-lambda2-distance?rq=1) section. The answer given there is quite short though.

Answer (score 0):

> So I don't know how he can say that the characteristics repeat or maybe I'am missing something.

You're missing that he is talking about the 'characteristics' of the standing wave, and not the instantaneous voltage. He's talking about whether the amplitude of the standing wave has a peak or minimum, is at an antinode or a node, as you move along the line. That repeats at half a wavelength.

One of the reasons we study standing waves is that before modern equipment like VNAs, it has been the only measurement method we could use. In fact even these days, if we want to move into a higher frequency RF region where we haven't built a VNA yet, we're back using the old standing wave methods. The reason is that we can measure the amplitude of an RF signal with a very simple and wideband diode detector. When we combine that with a [slotted line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slotted_line), we can plot how the standing wave changes with distance, and so calculate reflection coefficients. The ratio of the max and min amplitudes gives us the magnitude of the reflection, and we can infer its phase from the position of the max or min along the line.

As a diode detector simply measures the amplitude of the wave, not the instantaneous voltage, things repeat along the slotted line at λ/2, not at λ.

Comment: What is the difference? what do you mean by characteristics?

Comment: Does it imply absolute values?

Comment: @Orpheus Ask your prof what he means by charactersitics. If he meant instaneous voltage, he'd have probably said that. Think of it this way, what features (another word for characteristics) **does** repeat at half a wavelength in a standing wave?